# Specific removing all duplicates with R

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, data.table

For example I have two columns:

```
 Var1 Var2
 1     12
 1     65
 2     68
 2     98
 3     49
 3     24
 4      8
 5     67
 6     12
```

And I need to display only values which are unique for column Var1:

```
 Var1 Var2
 4      8
 5     67
 6     12
```

I can do you like this:

```
 mydata=mydata[!unique(mydata$Var1),]
```

But when I use the same formula for my large data set with about 1 million observations, nothing happens - the sample size is still the same.  Could you please explain my why?

Thank you!

Comment: you should look at what `unique(mydata$Var1)` gives you and then what `!unique(mydata$Var1)` gives and then what `mydata[!unique(mydata$Var1), ]` gives

Comment: @Gregor Sorry, didn`t notice that!

Comment: The irony that a post about removing duplicates was deemed to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table` (as it seem to be tagged with it) I would do

```
indx <- setDT(DT)[, .I[.N == 1], by = Var1]$V1 
DT[indx]
#    Var1 Var2
# 1:    4    8
# 2:    5   67
# 3:    6   12
```

Or... as @eddi reminded me, you can simply do

```
DT[, if(.N == 1) .SD, by = Var1]
```

Or (per the mentioned duplicates) with [v >= 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) you could also do something like

```
setDT(DT, key = "Var1")[!(duplicated(DT) | duplicated(DT, fromLast = TRUE))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df <- data.frame(Var1=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6), Var2=c(12,65,68,98,49,24,8,67,12) );
df[ave(1:nrow(df),df$Var1,FUN=length)==1,];
##   Var1 Var2
## 7    4    8
## 8    5   67
## 9    6   12
```

This will work even if the `Var1` column is not ordered, because `ave()` does the necessary work to collect groups of equal elements (even if they are non-consecutive in the grouping vector) and map the result of the function call (`length()` in this case) back to each element that was a member of the group.

---

Regarding your code, it doesn't work because this is what `unique()` and its negation returns:

```
unique(df$Var1);
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
!unique(df$Var1);
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

As you can see, `unique()` returns the actual unique values from the argument vector. Negation returns true for zero and false for everything else.

Thus, you end up row-indexing using a short logical vector (it will be short if there were any duplicates removed by `unique()`) consisting of TRUE where there were zeroes, and FALSE otherwise.