# create a column based on repetition in another column

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a table with several columns and in one of them I need to create a loop that flows down the column and if the same number is present twice another column is created (adding a "p" for example) and in which are present only once in the same column created earlier is added for example "-". Anyone?

the column have Barcodes `TCGA-3M-AB47-01A-22R-A414-31` I need the `AB47`

```
for(code in tabela$Barcode){
     t=sapply(strsplit(as.character(code), "-"), function(x) x[[2]]) #to extract the AB47
```

Comment: Please share a small example with sample input and desired output.

Comment: input: column x - A;A;C;B;C;D;E;F  output: column y - P;P;P;-;P;-;-;-

Comment: `y = c("-", "P")[(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = T)) + 1]`, using as input `x = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")`   (make things copy/paste-able to make people happy!)

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially equivalent to the [common](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21831769/903061) find [all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19392332/903061) duplicates question. (Which is, ironically, [very](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24881855/903061) widely [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29955163/903061).)

For a vector `x` like `x = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")`, the most common answer is to use the `duplicated` function twice, once with `fromLast = T` to flag **all** duplicates. This will give a boolean vector indicating whether each value is duplicated. Adding 1 to the boolean converts it from `TRUE`/`FALSE` to `2`/`1`, which we can use as a subsetting index of your desired markings:

```
y = c("-", "P")[(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = T)) + 1]
```